# vue js props reset a timer

Tags: javascript, timer, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<template>
    <span>{{time}}</span>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Timer',
    data () {
      return {
        time: 0
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      setInterval(() => {
        ++this.time
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
</script>
```

The parent

```
<template>
  <div class="tetris">
    <timer></timer>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import Timer from './Timer'
  export default {
    name: 'Game',
    components: {
      Timer: Timer
    },
   }
```

What is the best way to reset the timer here from the parent? 
I want to avoid emitting events as this would result in all uses of the timer being reset. Is the best option to pass in a prop eg "start" "stop" "reset"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a prop and watching it could be a good way to handle this if you're hoping to propagate events from the parent to the child. In general, communication of data between parent and child components should be done with props for parent-to-child communication and emitting events for child-to-parent communication.

There are, of course, additional libraries available for managing inter-component communication, but the above generally holds true for pure Vue.js code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a good way instead of increasing the timer in the child make it in the parent data and increment it in the parent and use props to pass it to the child and you can reset it in the parent when you like  >> you can copy the code below and see the results

> > child code

```
  <template>
<span>{{timer}}</span>
 </template>
 <script>
 export default {
  name: 'Timer',
   data () {
  return {

     }
   },
      props:{timer:Number},
      mounted() {

        }
   }
  </script>
```

> > parent code

```js
<script>
  import Timer from './Timer'
  export default {
    name: 'Game',
    data(){
      return {
        timerInit:0
      },
    components: {
      Timer: Timer
    },
    mounted(){
      setInterval(()=>{
        ++this.timerInit ;
        console.log(this.timerInit);
      },1000)
    },
 methods:{
      clickHandler(){
        this.timerInit = 0 ;
        console.log(this.timerInit);
      }
    }

   }
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="tetris">
    <timer:timer="timerInit"/>
    <button @click="clickHandler">reset</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I think this is coupling the timer to the parent too tightly imo.

Comment: Ok its better to use events and props